# PushBack Objects on a vector c++

Tags: c++, vector

I have this:

```
void StudentRegister::ReadDataFromFile(){
try{
    streampos begin,end;        
    char delimeter[3] = {',', '\n', '\0'};
    int numChars = 0, tmpNumChars = 0;
    int pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, startIndex = 0;
    ifstream file1("Students.txt", ios::in);
    if (!file1) throw MyExceptions();
    begin = file1.tellg();
    file1.seekg (0, ios::end);
    end = file1.tellg();
    int size =  end - begin;
    file1.seekg(0, ios::beg);      
    char charField[size];
    Student student;
    int k = 0;
    while(file1.getline(charField, size, '\n'))
    { 
        char *tmpCharField1 = charField;                        
        numChars = file1.gcount();
        CustomString tmpStudent(tmpCharField1, numChars);
        pos1 = tmpStudent.findCharacter(&delimeter[0], startIndex);
        CustomString tmpStudentCode = tmpStudent.subString(startIndex, pos1);
        pos2 = tmpStudent.findCharacter(&delimeter[0], (pos1 + 1));
        CustomString tmpFirstName = tmpStudent.subString((pos1 + 1), pos2);
        pos3 = tmpStudent.findCharacter(&delimeter[2], (pos2 + 1));
        CustomString tmpSecondName = tmpStudent.subString((pos2 + 1), pos3);
        student = Student(tmpStudentCode, tmpFirstName, tmpSecondName);
        this->StudentVector.push_back(&student);
        numChars = 0;
        k++;
        if (k == 4){
            cout << this->StudentVector.size()<< endl;
            for (int i = 0 ; i < this->StudentVector.size(); i ++){
              vector<CustomString> tt = this->StudentVector.at(i)->PrintData();
              for (int j =0; j < tt.size(); j++){
                 tt.at(j).PrintData();
              }

           }}            
    }        
    file1.close();
   }}}
```

Student PrintData is like that:

```
//Print Data Method
vector<CustomString> Student::PrintData(){
char tmp1[] = {'S','t','u','d','e','n','t','C','o','d','e','='};
char tmp2[] = {'F','i','r','s','t','N','a','m','e','='};
char tmp3[] = {'S','e','c','o','n','d','N','a','m','e','='};
vector<CustomString> tmpStudentVector;
CustomString tmp1String(tmp1, 12);
CustomString tmp2String(tmp2, 10);
CustomString tmp3String(tmp3, 11);
tmpStudentVector.push_back(tmp1String);
tmpStudentVector.push_back(this->Code);
tmpStudentVector.push_back(tmp2String);
tmpStudentVector.push_back(this->FirstName);
tmpStudentVector.push_back(tmp3String);
tmpStudentVector.push_back(this->SecondName);
for (int i = 0 ; i < this->StudentCourses.size(); i ++){
    vector<CustomString> tmpCourseVector = ((Course)(this->StudentCourses.at(i))).PrintData();
    for (int j = 0; j < tmpCourseVector.size(); j++){
        tmpStudentVector.push_back(tmpCourseVector.at(j));
    }    
} 
return tmpStudentVector;
}
```

while CustomString PrintData is like that:

```
//Print CandidateString
void CustomString::PrintData(){
for (int i = 0 ; i < this->NumberOfChars ; i ++){
    cout << this->CandidateString[i] << " " ;
}
cout << endl;
}
```

This is the StudentRegister class where the ReadDataFromFile is:

```
class StudentRegister{
public:
  StudentRegister();  //Constructor
  StudentRegister(const StudentRegister &);  //Copy Constructor      
  vector<Student *> getStudentVector(); //StudentVector Getter     
  void setStudentVector(vector<Student *> &); //StudentVector Setter    
  void ReadDataFromFile(); //Read Data From Excel
  bool FindStudentOnVector(CustomString &); //Find if student exists
  Student GetStudentFromVector(CustomString &); //Get Student from StudentVector
  bool FindCourseOnVector(CustomString &); //Find if Course exists  
  bool operator() (const Course &, const Course &); //Compare function, Needed to construct the Map    
  void PrintData(); //PrintData Method
  ~StudentRegister(); //Destructor
private:     
  vector<Student *> &StudentVector; //StudentVector Property     
  CustomString &ErrorString;     
};
```

Now do not ask why I an using all this code to return and print just all the nessecary properties, it is an assignment i do no have to use any string class or any relative string.h method. I have to use only char and pointers. The strange is that this->StudentVector on ReadDataFromFile() when I try to print the Student objects I get only the final object where is Student number 4, The size of StudentVector is 4, the code above in ReadDataFromFile() has a breakpoint for debugging there where k == 4 is checked.It seems the vector holds only the final object.Any suggestion?

Comment: `push_back(&student)` - you are always adding a pointer to the exact same `Student` object, which you also reuse in each iteration. So all the pointers in the vector point to the exact same object

Comment: You're not allowed to use standard classes such as `std::string`, but you're allowed to use illegal, non-standard C++ syntax like this: `char charField[size];`?  This should be `std::vector<char> charField(size);`  Also, the restrictions such as "only use pointers" shows that a simple program can easily turn into a mess.

Comment: if I delete student, with delete student will be ok?

Comment: No, because your pointers will still point to that object

Comment: delete student?

Comment: how can i add a new student object to the vector?

Comment: @Konstantinosdms -- Why are you using `vector<Student*>`?  Why are you not using `vector<Student>`?  I think you took the "no pointers" restriction overboard.  That doesn't mean everything must be pointers.  Then the solution would simply be: `StudentVector.push_back(student);`

Comment: Before I use vector<Student *> I had vector<Student> and I get the same problem, so I tried to see if vectors with pointers were a sollution to my problem.

Comment: What was the problem when you used `vector<Student>`?  By introducing pointers, you made the problem worse.  Please post the `Student` class.

Comment: Please read [example]. I'm asking you to do extra work. Work you may not want to do. Work you may not see the value in doing. You may not have time to make a [example]. What you don't have time for is randomly adding `*` and `&` throughout your code. Either take the time to make a [example] or eat your spaghetti.

Comment: @Konstantinosdms Sometimes it's easier to forget the restrictions and write the code using idiomatic C++.  Once you get the program working, you finagle the code so that you end up using a pointer or two in the code.  Better to start with an easier to code, working example and work backwards from there.  Right now, you have stars and ampersands all over the place without any coherency, so much so that you've lost track of things.

Comment: A note on `delete`. Only `delete` things that you know were allocated with `new`. Anything else should not be `delete`ed. If you don't know where it came from and how it was made, do not `delete`. Be careful with `new` and `delete`. They should be considered  advanced topics.